# Simulating a Gaussian (Ornstein Uhlenbeck) process with an exponentially decaying covariance function

Tags: r, probability, simulation, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

I'm trying to generate many draws (i.e., realizations) of
 a Gaussian process $e_i(t)$, $1\leq t \leq T$ with mean 0 and covariance 
function $\gamma(s,t)=\exp(-|t-s|)$.

Is there an efficient  way to do this that wouldn't involve computing the square 
root of a $T \times T$ covariance matrix? Alternatively can 
anyone recommend an `R` package to do this?

Comment: It's a stationary process (looks close to a simple version of an OU process). Is it uniformly sampled?

Comment: The R package `mvtnorm` has `rmvnorm(n, mean, sigma)` where `sigma` is the covariance matrix; you'd have to construct the covariance matrix for your sampled / selected $t$s yourself, though.

Comment: @jb Presumably $T$ is *huge,* otherwise the OP wouldn't be asking to avoid the matrix decomposition (which is implicit in `rmvnorm`).

Comment: @cardinal I agree, this is a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Gaussian process. (It would be great if the "Ornstein Uhlenbeck" keyword could be edited into the question and/or title.  It would get this question the more traffic it deserves)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes.** *There is a very efficient (linear time) algorithm, and the intuition for it comes directly from the uniformly-sampled case.*

Suppose we have a partition of $[0,T]$ such that $0=t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n = T$.

**Uniformly sampled case**

In this case we have $t_i = i \Delta$ where $\Delta = T/n$. Let $X_i := X(t_i)$ denote the value of the discretely sampled process at time $t_i$.

It is easy to see that the $X_i$ form an AR(1) process with correlation $\rho = \exp(-\Delta)$. Hence, we can generate a sample path $\{X_t\}$ for the partition as follows
$$
X_{i+1} = \rho X_i + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_{i+1} \>,
$$
where $Z_i$ are iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $X_0 = Z_0$.

**General case**

We might then imagine that it could be possible to do this for a *general* partition. In particular, let $\Delta_i = t_{i+1} - t_i$ and $\rho_i = \exp(-\Delta_i)$. We have that
$$
\gamma(t_i,t_{i+1}) = \rho_i \>,
$$
and so we might guess that
$$
X_{i+1} = \rho_i X_i + \sqrt{1-\rho_i^2} Z_{i+1} \>. 
$$

Indeed, $\mathbb E X_{i+1} X_i = \rho_i$ and so we at least have the correlation with the neighboring term correct.

The result now follows by telescoping via the tower property of conditional expectation. Namely,
$$
\newcommand{\e}{\mathbb E} \e X_i X_{i-\ell} = \e( \e(X_i X_{i-\ell} \mid X_{i-1} )) = \rho_{i-1} \mathbb E X_{i-1} X_{i-\ell} = \cdots = \prod_{k=1}^\ell \rho_{i-k} \>,
$$
and the product telescopes in the following way
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\ell \rho_{i-k} = \exp\Big(-\sum_{k=1}^\ell \Delta_{i-k}\Big) = \exp(t_{i-\ell} - t_i) = \gamma(t_{i-\ell},t_i) \>.
$$

This proves the result. Hence the process can be generated on an arbitrary partition from a sequence of iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables in $O(n)$ time where $n$ is the size of the partition.

**NB**: This is an *exact* sampling technique in that it provides a sampled version of the desired process with the exactly correct [finite-dimensional distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-dimensional_distribution). This is in contrast to Euler (and other) discretization schemes for more general SDEs, which incur a bias due to the approximation via discretization.

Comment: Just a few more remarks. (1) To get a good idea of what the continuous time process looks like, $n$ and $T$ must be chosen so that $\Delta$ is small, say less than $0.1$. (2) The  inverse covariance (*precision*) matrix for the timeseries vector is tri-diagonal, as is its Cholesky root.

Comment: @Yves: Thanks for your comments. To be clear, the procedure I've outlined gives an *exact* realization of the continuous-time process sampled on the corresponding partition; in particular, there is *no* discretization error like there is in typical Euler-scheme approximation to more general SDEs. The inverse Cholesky, as shown by the construction in the answer has nonzero terms only on the diagonal and lower off-diagonal, so it's a little simpler than tridiagonal.

Comment: Great answer!  Does this generalize to the general OU process with arbitrary scale, $\gamma(t_i, t_j) = \exp(\alpha \; |t_i - t_j|)$?  It seems like it might.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the decomposed covariance matrix by incomplete Cholesky decomposition or any other matrix decomposition technique. Decomposed matrix should be TxM, where M is only a fraction of T.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_Cholesky_factorization

Comment: Can you give an explicit form of the Cholesky decomposition here? I think that the answer by cardinal achieves just that, if you think about it, by expressing $X_i$ as a function of the history.

Comment: The algorithm is a little too long to summarize. You can find an excellent description here: [Kernel ICA](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/kernelICA-jmlr.pdf), page 20. Note that this algorithm is *incomplete*, meaning it doesn't calculate the entire decomposition but rather an approximation (hence it is much faster). I have published code for this algorithm in the KMBOX toolbox, you can download it here: [km_kernel_icd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kmbox/files/src/km_kernel_icd.m).